# Reporting Services availability SQL Server Express 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am trying to add Reporting Services to my already installed version of SQL Server Express 2008 R2. I am installing it on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard edition box.

When ever I run the install program to add extra features Reporting services is not listed.

I have installed (I think) all the prerequisites needed IIS, ASP etc but to no avail. Reporting services are just not visible in my features list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SSRS is only available in the [SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services Downloa](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=b5d1b8c3-fda5-4508-b0d0-1311d670e336&displaylang=en)d, not the standard one

Comment: Here's a link to the 2008 R2 version: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e08766ce-fc9d-448f-9e98-fe84ad61f135&displaylang=en

Comment: Many thanks that did the trick  - I was under the impression that R2 had all SSRS features

Comment: Link to express 2008 R2 with sp1 http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26729