# Installing features in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have existing installation of SQL server 2008 r2 express. 
I need to add SSRS features to my installation. So I found this topic, whic says that I have to download SQLserver express with advanced services. 
[Reporting Services availability SQL Server Express 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062795/reporting-services-availability-sql-server-express-2008-r2)
I did download that packet, but here's a screenshot of what I got:

[image]

Which indicates that all features are installed and no way to add SSRS. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
  I selected existing installation on step two of the wizard. See screenshot below:
[image]

When I try to upgrade, to new version, there's what I've got:

[image]

Comment: Did you choose the same instance name as your original install when running the Advanced setup?

Comment: @JoeStefanelli, I believe so, I added the screen from the second step to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you have to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 with Advanced Services first, and then add the feature afterward.  SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and SQL Server 2008 R2 with Advanced Services are technically different "versions", but an upgrade path is supported. I would try to upgrade - run the package without adding new features - and then see if the Reporting Services functionality is available.

[image]

Comment: So, select new installation or add shared features? I tried that, but Fetures list look the same.

Comment: I'd do the add features - with the list like the one you show above - and let it complete.  Then try to add features again.  I think the first pass will upgrade the instance to Advanced Services.

Comment: I cannot run it for the first time, because it says: to continue, select a feature to install. If all features are already selected these features are installed.

Comment: Are you not able to upgrade -> see image above.

Comment: when I'm trying to upgrade, I get: there are no features selected to upgrade. (see updated post)

Comment: That's no good - I expected it to be there.  Here's a link that shows other people have had the same issue as you -> http://forums.asp.net/t/1317785.aspx/1.  Their solution was to uninstall and install Advanced Services from scratch.